# struts2 with jquery radio button event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, struts2, radio-button

I have an issue with the radio button event handling using jquery. I am new to JQuery but trying handle the html form elements events using JQuery. In the recent days I have added JQuery datepicker to my form which is working fine and now trying to add radio button and handle the checked and unchecked events of the radio button to hide and show some parts of the html elements( text fields, selection and other elements ).

Here is my code

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="tags" uri="/struts-tags"%>
 <html>
 <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <tags:form name="someForm" action="someAction" method="post">
  <tags:textfield key="someActionClass.transactionDate" id="datepicker"     label="Transaction Date" />
  <tags:radio list="#{'1':'One Time','2':'Recurring'}" id="tType" lable="Transaction Type" name="recurringOrOneTime"></tags:radio>


  <div class="recuType">
    <h1>this part should be hiden/show depending upon radio button events</h1>
  </div>

  <script src="jquery/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>

  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true
   });

    $("#tType").change(function(){
    alert('Radio Button event raised');
    });

   </script>
   </tags:form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have added the JQuery lib that I have downloaded for my JQuery datepicker in jquery directory as you can see from this link tag

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery-ui.css">
```

so, When I click on the radio buttons no event is getting generated. for the testing purpose I am trying to popup and alert message with the selected radio button value but no luck. I have gone through so many posts and examples and most of them are using html input tag and I want to use struts2 tag elements.

Is there any thing wrong I am doing with my code? or missed any library to include? please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$("input[name='recurringOrOneTime']").change(function(){
        alert('Radio Button event raised');
        });
```

Instead of

```
$("#tType").change(function(){
    alert('Radio Button event raised');
    });
```

id must be unique in a html document, you're assigning 2 radio buttons the same id.

Comment: so how to assign two different ID's in my case. Since I am using struts2 and we are supposed to give a list for radio buttons and how I can add two different ID's?

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to assign id to them? Usually radio buttons only need name attribute for form submission and maybe a class for styling.

Comment: now I am able to trigger the events but my next requirement which is hide the html elements like textbox , select and other elements which were placed in <div class="recuType">
        <h1>this part should be hiden/show depending upon radio button   events</h1>
  </div>
I am able to hide the plain text but when it comes to textfield's or other form elements it is not. How to perform this hide and show operations for them. Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You can change two things:

1. change the attribute `id` to `class`.
2. Bind the event on class name instead.

---

Change

```
id="tType"
```

to

```
class="tType"
```

and now bind the event:

```
$(".tType").change(function(){
    alert('Radio Button event raised');
});
```

or even you can refer it with `input[type="radio"], :radio` etc:

```
$("form input[type='radio']").change(function(){ // or $("form :radio")
    alert('Radio Button event raised');
});
```